# Multiple error messages trying to send file to server using Requests and Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-requests

I'm currently using the Requests library to send a file to a remote server from a form(InMemoryUploadedFile). I initially sent the 'file'(`file = self.request.FILES.get('file')`) as part of my payload, and when I ran the code I received a JSON error response from the server that says:

> {"outcome":"error","message":"string contains null byte"}

Upon further reading(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/uploads/) it seems like it would make sense to read the file. So I decided to read the file using the .chunks() method(in case you have files larger than 2.5MB), but now I'm getting a:

> {"outcome":"error","message":"invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"}

And if I use `.multiple_chunks()` I get a server 500 error.

Does anyone have any ideas what steps could be taken to resolve this issue?

```
class AddDocumentView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('users:login')
    form_class = FileUploadForm
    template_name = 'docman/forms/add-document.html'
    success_message = 'Document was successfully added'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
        file = self.request.FILES.get('file')
        if not self.post_to_server(file, user.id):
            messages.error(self.request,  "Upload failed", extra_tags='alert alert-danger')
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post_to_server(self, file, cid):
        url = 'https://exampleapi.herokuapp.com/api/files/'
        headers = {'token': 'secret-token93409023'}
        payload = {'file': file.chunks(), 'client_id': cid}
        r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        print(r.text)
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it had to do with me sending the file as part of the payload, which doesn't multipart encode the upload. So what I had to do was send the file as the correct 'file' parameter which does properly multipart encode the upload.

```
class AddDocumentView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('users:login')
    form_class = FileUploadForm
    template_name = 'docman/forms/add-document.html'
    success_message = 'Document was successfully added'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
        file = self.request.FILES.get('file')
        if not self.post_to_server(file, user.id):
            messages.error(self.request,  "Upload failed", extra_tags='alert alert-danger')
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post_to_server(self, file, cid):
        url = 'https://exampleapi.herokuapp.com/api/files/'
        headers = {'token': 'secret-token93409023'}
        # Remove files as part of payload
        payload = {'client_id': cid}
        files = {'file': file}
        # Place 'files' as file paramter to be properly multipart encoded
        r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=payload, headers=headers)
        print(r.text)
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```